# AdvertisingIdClient without google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

We ran into a problem and cannot add Google Play Services lib to our application.

The problem is that the lib introduces 24,000 methods and a single dex can only contain 65536 methods.

Is there a way to get the Google Advertising ID without a reference to Google Play Services?

Comment: Duplicate question, here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097506/using-the-new-android-advertiser-id-inside-an-sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Google Play Services 7.0.0 Release 23 you can now choose to only include the parts of Google Play Services you need.

In this case in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0'
```

That will drastically reduce the number of methods which are added.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no documented API, other than Google Play Services, to retrieve the advertising ID. You could try to use Proguard to strip unneeded packages from Google Play Services to reduce method references, but *obviously* be very careful of what you strip as you'll run into `NoClassDefFound` exceptions if you strip required classes/packages.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't , Only Google Powered Devices can get `AdvertisingIdClient`  , if your Targeting a Non-Google Devices then , try using other Ad-services..

Comment: that's not at all what he's asking.