# Advertise ID without play services

Tags: android, ads

I would like to know is there a way to fetch android device Ad-id without having a dependency of google play services. By using [this](https://github.com/datatheorem/AdvertisingID-Android/blob/master/advertising_id/securecode/dt/com/advertising_id_example/AdvertisingIdClient.java), I was able to fetch Ad-id but it has a dependency of google play services. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The advertising ID (“advertising ID”) is a user-resettable, unique, anonymous ID for advertising, provided by Google Play services. so you cannot get it without google play services. read [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en) documentation for more info. and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846108/how-to-get-advertising-id-in-android) is an easy way to get advertising id.

read [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk) documentation also.