# Best way to link a FCM token to a device?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a server that sends messages using FCM to clients depending on what happens (temperature and/or humidity change, a door is opened, etc.).

But if the token can change, how can I keep track of the device to send messages to the correct one (w/o using a login system)?

I was thinking to link the token to the sim iccid in a database, is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you can create a random unique id to link with a device and send with the token without user having to actually login?

Comment: But it will change too if the app is reinstalled

Comment: I think it's better to use unique topic for each user for example topic_useremail and send messages to topic. No matter change device.

Comment: When the token changes the device has to tell you about the new token - that's how you know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 05/18/2017:

Starting Android O, `ANDROID_ID` will now be [different per app per user in the device](https://youtu.be/1N9KveJ-FU8?t=22m53s).

---

Original Answer:

If you're looking for a *long lasting* (possibly permanent) ID that you can use, I guess you can make use of [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID):

> <sub>String ANDROID_ID</sub>
>
> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.
>
> > Note: When a device has [multiple users](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers) (available on certain devices running Android 4.2 or higher), each user appears as a completely separate device, so the **ANDROID_ID** value is unique to each user.
>
> Constant Value: "android_id"

However, there are still some factors that you should consider depending on your use-case. I recommend going through the [Best Practices for Unique Identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html) documentation.

FCM wise, it is usually associated with a user, hence it is commonly paired with the user details.

Answer (score 1):

Use device's advertising id. It won't change unless the user manually changes it. Please check the thread [How to get Advertising ID in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846108/how-to-get-advertising-id-in-android)