# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Notification_key invalidated when removing one device among many

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was playing around with adding and removing device tokens from an FCM device group, and I noticed that if I remove a device from a group, and even if another device exists in that group, FCM cancels the `notification_key` (detected through trying to reuse the same key to add a new device). This is very bad for me, because it means **I can't add new devices to the same group from which a device was removed but others are still there**.

Here is some code to confirm this (please filling the appropriate values):

## 1. Create device group with one device.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification \
  -H 'authorization: key=YOUR_KEY' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'project_id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID' \
  -d '{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "some-group-identifier",
   "registration_ids": ["device-token-1"]
}'
```

This returns the notification key, which I must feed to the next call where we add a new device.

```
{
  "notification_key": "my-new-notification-key"
}
```

## 2. Add new device to the existing group.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification \
  -H 'authorization: key=YOUR_KEY' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'project_id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID' \
  -d '{
   "operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name": "some-group-identifier",
   "notification_key": "my-new-notification-key",
   "registration_ids": ["device-token-2"]
}'
```

Response is same as (1).

## 3. Remove this last device from group.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification \
  -H 'authorization: key=YOUR_KEY' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'project_id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID' \
  -d '{
   "operation": "remove",
   "notification_key_name": "some-group-identifier",
   "notification_key": "my-new-notification-key",
   "registration_ids": ["device-token-2"]
}'
```

Success. Same response as (1) and (2).

## 4. Attempt to add a new device to the same group.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification \
  -H 'authorization: key=YOUR_KEY' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'project_id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID' \
  -d '{
   "operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name": "some-group-identifier",
   "notification_key": "my-new-notification-key",
   "registration_ids": ["device-token-3"]
}'
```

FAIL. Response is `400`, with `{"error": "notification_key not found"}`. I can't but think this is a bug? Otherwise how are we expected to dynamically resize a group of devices?

Comment: I tried your cURLs and everything works as expected. please use this after every operation `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=your_key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "notification": { "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark", "body": "5 to 1", "icon": "firebase-logo.png", "click_action": "http://localhost:8081" }, "to":"notification_key" }' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"` to make sure the token have been correctly added/removed. i used your cURL commands minus the `-H 'cache-control: no-cache'` part. ps: now i can comment ^^

Comment: Good that you can comment. :) Why do you think the `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` is needed? It's not a very good option for me, given that the system is real time and might be handling many devices, so that's an additional network trip I'd rather not do.

Comment: And the cache-control should have no effect on this, if it did then that's an entirely new issue I believe.

Comment: I too think cache control shouldn't affect anything , but to be complete I wrote that I didn't use it . I don't know the details of your system but the notification I suggested is just a way to debug , if you can afford to use it just right now it could help understand what's going on , since as I said it worked fine for me . If you can , do a fresh test and at each step confirm with sending a notification what's happening . Edit your question with the new results as it might help someone else in answering you as well , thanks .

Comment: Sounds good, will test it with your suggestions and report back. Thanks MaX.

Comment: MaX, no luck. When I try to broadcast (the POST call you do above using the endpoint `/send`) after I remove on of the devices, I get `200` but no body, suggesting that the broadcasting did not go well. Sure enough, after I try to add a new device after I removed the second one, it fails, like we know it does in my case.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the responses you get? That notification (where the `to` field is the group notification key ) should return something like `"success" : 1, "failure" : 0` as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table5). Please edit your question with the number of successes and failures obtained sending a notification to the group after every step in your question. Also, what are you using for this tests? cURL from shell, postman ..? Please refrain from using your application (as it may have errors) and stick to pure http requests

Comment: I am using curl. Will update the question.

Comment: Actually, before I do that, I have a theory about FCM considering my two tokens to belong to the same device, and as such when I remove one of them both are gone. Let me verify that first.

Comment: SOVLED. Will post the answer. It's what I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the `registration_ids` I was using were from the same chrome app, even when I changed the code of the chrome app thinking this will make it appear as a new one.

Only after creating THREE chrome extensions and generating a `registration_id` for each did FCM start treating them as separate apps. After this it all worked perfectly.

Thanks @MaX for the help.

Comment: Glad you solved! Although i'm still curious about the number of successes you would have received notifying the group after adding the two tokens, if 1 or 2 . Good job nonetheless , Cheers

Comment: I get 1 when its one device, then 2 when its two devices, then one again after I remove one. It's all good. :D

Comment: @n_x_l what do you mean by "Only after creating THREE chrome extensions", how exactly you created them?

Comment: Hi @GuseynIsmayylov, simply follow the chrome tutorials for creating extensions. I have since moved away from this to sorry I can't be of more help to you.