# Is the firebase cloud messaging registration token per app or per device?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I distribute two apps x and y (under the same developer account), will a user who has both apps installed have the same token for both apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A registration token is associated with an *app instance* -- an app's installation (also mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752512/4625829)). Since it's two different apps, it should generate different tokens.

With that said, I would suggest making different projects per app in your developer account.