# Getting AAID with Google Play Services Ads 17.0.0+

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

To obtain AAID it is obligatory to add

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:x.y.z"
```

dependency to `dependencies` function in gradle file, then implement what's described [How to get Advertising ID in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846108/how-to-get-advertising-id-in-android-programmatically/39236765)

But from 17.0.0 version of `play-services-ads`, according to https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes#17.0.0 `AdMob App ID` is required in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Crash otherwise.

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*source: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml*

It's strange to me. I don't use AdMob, so I don't want to write messy code in `AndroidManifest.xml`. It looks like this is the way for Google to subtly force usage of AdMob for greenfield projects.

Which dependency is optimal for getting AAID nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- stay on `16.0.0`
- upgrade to at least `18.3.0` and use sample `AdMob App ID`
- upgrade to at least `18.3.0` and set up default project in Firebase AdMob. Provide `AdMob App ID` from there.

I don't observe any side effect with 1st and 2nd solution. Getting AAID is fine. Haven't tried 3rd, but should be fine.